# How Can I Subdivide Only Part of a Grease Pencil Stroke (Ver. 2.92.0)?

Tags: edit-mode, grease-pencil

When in **Edit Mode** for a Grease Pencil object, I can go to the **Stroke** menu at the top of the screen and select **Subdivide**. But this will always subdivide the entire Grease Pencil object. How can I subdivide only part of one stroke within the Grease Pencil object, specifically between two particular vertices? In the included picture, there are not enough vertices between the circled ones, but I can't figure out how to add vertices only to this area. What's worse, even if I give up and simply opt to use the blanket Subdivide option (hoping to get more vertices where I need them even as I'm forced to add more of them where I don't), it seems that vertices are still not being added in this specific region. Why is this? What am I failing to understand about how Grease Pencil geometry behaves?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select only two points where you want to subdivide, and select *Stroke* > *Subdivide*.

[image]

Or just right click on the context menu and select subdivide.

[image]

Note that you can modify the settings for the tools and the post processing for the draw tools to get better detail and optimize how control points are distributed on the drawn lines.

[image]

For more information **read the manual** https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/modes/draw/tools/draw.html#tool-grease-pencil-draw-draw

Comment: Your post is straightforward, but it doesn't completely address my confusion, because it worked at first, but then later did not work. What appears to be happening is that ONLY SOMETIMES can I subdivide the space between two points. In my latest scenario, some edges within an object can be subdivided by selecting two neighboring points, and other edges can't be. This, in a shape that is completely enclosed, and originally created as a drawn ellipse with both a stroke and a fill. What could possibly explain this?

Comment: Please update your question and explain clearly what is not working there. Show a concrete example. It is hard to help you otherwise.

Comment: Done. Thanks for being such a trooper.

Comment: One thing I think is missing from this answer is the advice to switch the selection mode to Points. In the question and the OP's associated answer - it looks like the OP is using Stroke selection mode.

Answer (score -1):

After some experimentation, it turns out that enclosed grease pencil objects, such as those which can be created with either the **ellipse** or the **box** tools while in **Draw** mode, have some curious quirk which prevents the Subdivide option from working properly on every edge of the stroke. Subdivide works for all but ONE edge. I'm assuming that this one edge, which cannot be subdivided by any conceivable means, is the edge that defines both the beginning and the end point of the stroke. Still, the behavior is curious and unexpected. To repeat the steps needed to see this problem, create a Grease Pencil Object and add to it an ellipse or a box. Go into **Edit Mode** and then select all vertices. Then, from the **Stroke** menu at the top of the screen, select **Subdivide** multiple times in a row. You will see that subdivisions happen to all edges except for one.

[image]

This explains why it is that sometimes I was able to subdivide an edge within a stroke, and other times I was not. What was happening was, in the course of continuing to edit my stroke and move it around in Sculpt mode, this single stubborn impossible-to-subdivide edge would eventually end up in any random location within the stroke, but without me knowing it even had this strange behavior. Occasionally settling on this one stroke as being the one that I would like to subdivide is what revealed the curious behavior, and also what made that behavior appear seemingly random. I still don't know why there is always one edge which can't be subdivided. But at least I now know why I couldn't subdivide Grease Pencil edges when I thought for sure I already knew how to do it.

Comment: The question was originally asked without full knowledge of the problem, which I later explained in more detail with an answer, in an effort to update it (as you requested), because that struck me as a more appropriate approach than rewording the entire question and, in so doing, making your response less relevant to the wording. Had I known you'd balk at my effort to edit it regardless, then I probably would have just left it as it was without committing any further work to it.